# How can I go about proving that vector $n$ is orthogonal to every vector $V_i$, such that $1\leq i \leq n-1$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, determinant, orthogonality

[image]

I need help with question $4a$ and $4b$.

Comment: One thing that I like to do in questions like this is try it out for a small case, like $n=2$, and see if I can make the way I solved it generalize.

Answer (score 0):

(a) Remember that if C is the cofactor matrix of A then
$$AC^T=C^TA=det(A)I$$
We have that n is the first column of C, therefore n is the first row of $C^T$, because of this equation $C^TA=det(A)I$, and the definition of matrix multiplicacion $(row \times column)$ 
$$ n^Tv_i=det(A)I_{(i+1)1}=0, \forall 1\leq i\leq n-1$$ 
(think of first row  of identity matrix)

(b) You can think of the cross-product, and find the relation of the 'normal vector' with n vector of the problem.